# NTP Meinberg GPS167: How to connect to a Ethernet?

Tags: linux, local-area-network, ntp, time-server

I have a Meinberg GPS167 NTP:
http://www.meinberg.de/english/products/gps167.htm

Although it doesnt have a ethernet RJ45 port. Is there any way to connect it to a LAN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These devices connect to a computer via the serial (RS232) interface.  You can then serve NTP to your LAN from the computer.

Comment: Hello Aaron, like: install a Linux that uses the meinberg to syncronise internally and then install a local NTP to serve the network?

Comment: Exactly, any distro should work. The NTP daemon should refer to the serial interface for it's source clock.  I haven't done this myself, but have looked into it.  The Meinberg device may have some documentation.